# chardinJs and Angular

Tags: angularjs, overlay, angularjs-directive, walkthrough

Currently I'm looking for a plugin/js that I can use to show my users a small walkthrough of my site. I have jquery and angular both running on my page.

I have been using Chardin.js (https://github.com/heelhook/chardin.js). This plugin works and is simple, however when i try to include angular elements chardin.js will not be able to find the elements to display.

SO I'm trying to find a way to integrate this plugin with angular. Unless there are some better plugins that work better for this in angular. Thanks!

Comment: I like Angular-Intro https://github.com/mendhak/angular-intro.js

Comment: There's also a port for Chardin https://github.com/jordanburke/angular-help-overlay

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Ben_Coding,

Angular-Intro is pretty good, light-weight, and no dependency on jQuery.

Comment: I have used ingular intro and it is really easy to use.

Comment: @KuN This does have a dependency on jQuery?

Comment: @DanielShillcock You can check the bower.json and package.json of both libs, none of them mentioned jQuery. It's been awhile but i don't recall including jQuery in my old Angular project with this one.